# Aggregating data issue

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

Dataset:

```
# Groups:   SITEPLOT [21,143]
   L4_KEY              HEMIAB SITEPLOT
   <fct>                <dbl> <fct>   
 1 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 1  
 2 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 100
 3 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 101
 4 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 102
 5 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 103
 6 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 104
 7 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 105
 8 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 107
 9 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 108
10 82g  Downeast Coast      0 ACAD 109
# ... with 21,133 more rows
```

HEMIAB indicates the abundance of a certain species. This dataset is on a plot level basis. I want to know how many distinct L4_KEYs have no abundance of this species, i.e. those which do not have any plots that have HEMIAB >0.  Since this dataset is not on the L4_KEY level, I'm having a really hard time figuring ou what seems like a simple solution. Any help would be great. I have tried various dplyr and aggregate solutions but can't get it to do it based on L4_KEY, not plot level. For some reason I'm having issues with this

Comment: In your description, it says `I want to know how many distinct L4_KEYs have no abundance`.  So, i used `length` and `n_distinct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the 'L4_KEY' column based on the values of 'HEMLAB' i.e. those having 'HEMLAB' greater than 0, get the `unique` elements, use `setdiff` from the `levels` of the 'L4_KEY', and get the `length` of those doesn't have any value greater than 0 (in `base R`)

```
length(setdiff(levels(df1$L4_KEY), unique(df1$L4_KEY[df1$HEMLAB > 0])))
```

---

Another option is to group by 'L4_KEY', `filter` those having `all` values in 'HEMLAB' less than or equal to 0, `ungroup` and get the `distinct` elements

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>%
   group_by(L4_KEY) %>%
   filter(all(HEMLAB <=0)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   distinct(L4_KEY) %>%
   droplevels()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't think to ungroup.

The only problem is this just gives me a number, rather than the actual identities of the L4_KEYS that match the criteria

Comment: @Skotani1 i updated by removing the `n_distinct` with `distinct`

Comment: @Skotani1 for the first solution, you can just remove the `length` wrapping to get those elements

Comment: it works with unique() , not distinct (). I appreciate your help

Comment: @Skotani1 that is strange though.  May be a version difference

Comment: There is something wrong. The number of levels of L4_KEY is 214, yet when I run this code for HEMIAB>0 and HEMIAB ==0t gives me more than 214, i.e. this is showing me L4_KEYS that have both HEMIAB=0 and HEMIAB not equal to 0, so the ```all``` part of this doesn't seem to be working . For some reason it only shows me one L4_KEY when I say HEMIAB>0, which I know is wrong

Comment: @Skotani1 it is reltaed to `droplevels`.  Try `droplevels` at the end because the `levels` attribute are not automaticaly dropped even though you remove those values.  It needs `droplevels` at the end or call `factor` again to reset

Comment: Same thing, HEMIAB>0, I only get 1 return L4, which is wrong.

Comment: @Skotani1 do you have `NA` elements in the columns

Comment: No, I think I figured it out. I was thinking about it incorrectly. There is only one L4 layer that has no "0" values, which does make sense. I got it now, thank you! i do wonder if there is a way to not have to run the code twice ; i.e. not have to switch HEMIAB>0 and HEMIAB==0, to create 2 columns

Comment: @Skotani1 my code can be tested with this reproducible example `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(all(Sepal.Length <= 6)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(Species)`